# "Error Fetching http headers" in SOAP request

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, soap, wsdl

I have working code in JS, which makes a working request:

```js
const login = 'login';
const password = 'password';
const basicAuthorizationToken = 'Basic token'

export async function authenticate() {
    const response = await fetch('/ws', 
        { 
            method: 'post',
            headers: {'Content-Type':'text/xml', 'Authorization': basicAuthorizationToken },
            credentials: 'omit', 
            body: '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://example.com/ws">' +
                    '<soapenv:Header/>' +
                    '<soapenv:Body>' +
                    '<ws:authorizationWSRequest>' +
                        '<ws:login>' + login + '</ws:login>' +
                        '<ws:password>' + password + '</ws:password>' +
                    '</ws:authorizationWSRequest>' +
                    '</soapenv:Body>' +
                '</soapenv:Envelope>'
       });

    const xml = await parseResponseToJson(response);
    const sessionId = xml.getElementsByTagName('ns2:sessionId')[0].value;
    sessionStorage.setItem('sessionId', sessionId);
```

but when I try in php like this

```php
$basicAuthorizationToken = 'Basic token';
$soapParameters = Array('login' => "login", 'password' => "password",
    'method'=> 'post',
    'credentials' => 'omit',
);
$ns = 'http://mysite/ws';
$headerbody = array('Content-Type'=> 'text/xml',
    'Authorization'=> $basicAuthorizationToken);
$headers = new \SoapHeader($ns, 'RequestorCredentials', $headerbody);
$this->client = new \SoapClient('https://example.com/wsdl.wsdl',$soapParameters);
$this->client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
$array = [
    'login' => 'login',
    'password' => 'password'
];
$response = $this->client->authorizationWS($array);
return  dump($response);
```

I getting response:

> "Error Fetching http headers"

I tried multiple variations but still getting that response.